# Is there any function in R similar to pd.crosstab in python?

Tags: python, r, pandas, crosstab

I am looking for a function in R similar to pd.crosstab in python where, I want to create contingency matrix between 2 columns based on the values of a third column's sum.

Example -

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3
A       | X       | 1
A       | Y       | 2
A       | Z       | 3
B       | X       | 1
B       | Y       | 2
B       | Z       | 3
```

Output

```
  | X | Y | Z
A | 1 | 2 | 3
B | 1 | 2 | 3
```

Comment: Have a look to the pandas documentation, it suits your need I guess https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html

Comment: Search for "reshape data.frame to wide format".

Comment: `tidyr::pivot_wider` is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is called crosstabs ie `xtabs`:

```
xtabs(Column3~Column1+Column2, df)
       Column2
Column1 X Y Z
      A 1 2 3
      B 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

For a reproducible example that uses a Tidyverse alternative, here is a solution that uses `tidyr::pivot_wider()` to widen the table (a function I find 100 times less confusing than `stats::reshape()`):

```r
# create example dataset
my_data <- data.frame(col1 = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 3),
                      col2 = rep(LETTERS[24:26], 2),
                      col3 = rep(1:3, 2))
# widen the data
library(tidyr)
pivot_wider(my_data,
            names_from = col2,
            values_from = col3)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   col1      X     Y     Z
#>   <chr> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 A         1     2     3
#> 2 B         1     2     3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>